# Using Seek Bar to zoom android Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, zooming, android-seekbar

this is my first question in stackoverflow. any help would be very much appreciated.
I am trying zoom a canvas using a seek bar, so depend on the progress of the seekbar, the canvas will zoom in and zoom out.

here is my code in the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seekbar Value : " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    CPaintView paint  =  (CPaintView) this.findViewById(R.id.cPaintView1);

    paint.zoomX = (float)progress;
    paint.zoomY = (float)progress;
    paint.invalidate();
}
```

then it will pass the progress value to the CPaintView class which contain the canvas:

```
public class CPaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    int color = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");

    Bitmap offScreenBitmap;
    Canvas offScreenCanvas;

    final int CIRCLE = 0;
    final int TRIANGLE = 1;
    final int SQUARE = 2;
    int shape = CIRCLE;
    private int mActivePointerId;
    float zoomX = 0;
    float zoomY = 0;

    public CPaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setup();
    }

    public CPaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setup();
    }

    public CPaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setup();
    }

    public void setup()
    {
        setOnTouchListener(this); // define event listener and start intercepting events 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // draw the off screen bitmap
        if(zoomX > 0)
        {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(zoomX, zoomY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(offScreenBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
        else
            canvas.drawBitmap(offScreenBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // get the x,y coordinates of the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE event

        int pointerIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
        {
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(i);
            pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            float y1 = y + 20;
            float x2 = x + 20;
            float y2 = y1 - 10;
            paint.setColor(color);

            float verts[] = {x, y, x, y1, x2, y2};
            int[] vertsColors = {color, color, color, color, color, color};


            switch(shape)
            {
                case CIRCLE:
                    offScreenCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint); break;// draw a red circle at the x,y coordinates specified by the user
                case TRIANGLE:
                    offScreenCanvas.drawVertices(Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES, verts.length, verts, 0, null, 0, vertsColors, 0, null, 0, 0, paint);break;
                case SQUARE:
                    offScreenCanvas.drawRect(x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10, paint); break; 
            }

            invalidate();
        }
                return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // create / re-create the off screen bitmap to capture the state of our drawing
        // this operation will reset the user's drawing
            offScreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            offScreenCanvas = new Canvas(offScreenBitmap);
    }
}
```

I am having problem with the onDraw method. The problem is, when I increase the seekbar progress, the whole canvas disappear and I try to draw on it, it seems like it doesn't draw. But when I decrease the seekbar progress back to 0, all the drawing comes back and I can see it again, including the drawing that seems like not working.

I am sorry for my bad english.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is conceptual with how scale works. Scaling at 0,0 is undefined. Scaling at 1f,1f is the default. The scaling isn't working much at all,

```
 if(zoomX > 0)
        {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(zoomX, zoomY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(offScreenBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
        else
            canvas.drawBitmap(offScreenBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

if the zoom is 0, then it'll properly draw the scaled bitmap. Because it'll skip your zoom step. else you have a scaling of like 50 which is basically going to maybe have the bitmap be a dot. Try getting the zoom to hover around 1. Something like zoom = 12 / (1 + progress) Then the zoom can range from like 12x to values less than zero. Your drawing seems like it should be there, it's just *WAAAAY* small. Except at zero where you skip that step and make it 1.